# Sliding a div up/ down on click on mobiles and modal view same div on desktop

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, breakpoints

I have seen a lot of examples for this question and most of them use jQuery for it. But I need a CSS alternative as I will have different placements and effects in different viewpoints.

***For ex:*** When the user visit the page and clicks on the '**SIGN UP**' button a div slides up from the bottom with a slight transparency and touch anywhere to slide it back down. Same should happen with the '**SIGN IN**' button.

**Just like this:**

[image: signup]

What I have achieved is very minimum as I am not good at CSS.
Fiddle: [my work](https://jsfiddle.net/Loudbu9a/)
and I checked [example taken](http://jsfiddle.net/6W7XD/) for some help.

CSS

```
html, body
    {
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body
    {
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), url(../images/bg.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    #google
    {
        background-color: #D34836;
        width:100%;
        height:35px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        border:none;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans serif;
        font-size:15px;
        border-radius:5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    }

    #container
    {
        margin-left:8%;
        margin-right:8%;
    }
    #greeting
    {
        width:100%;
        margin-top:28%;
        margin-bottom:32%;
    }
    #first_part, #second_part
    {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #first_part
    {
        font-size:38px;
        line-height:0.8;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }
    #second_part
    {
        font-size:22px;
    }
    #signup, #signin
    {
        font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans serif;
        font-size:15px;
        background-color:transparent;
        border: solid 1px;
        border-color:#FFFFFF;
        border-radius:5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        width:48%;
        height:35px;
    }
    #signin
    {
        margin-left: 3%;
  }
  #signup_container
  {
    color:#000000;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    height:50%;
    display: none;
  }
  #signup:focus + #signin
  {
    display: inline;
  }
  #signup:focus + #signin + #signup_container
  {
    display: block;
  }
```

Any kind of input will be of great help. If jQuery can be made to use I would still love to know the way and implement it.

**UPDATE**: I was hoping if breakpoint.js could be used for this purpose?

Comment: Using pure css I wouldn't say is possible as you need some way of triggering a change in classes then using transitions to move. At the very least you should have a collapsed div and open div CSS rules with 'transition' configured on the open div rule to change from one style to the other gracefully. 

This toggle would be served as vanilla Javascript too meaning that it wouldn't cause any compatibility issues. (also your links need round brackets on them to work correctly. Check over the mini-markdown rules to see what I mean).

Comment: Changed the links properly

Answer (score 0):

Your Jsfiddles links are dead/not working but i ll try to answer anyway.

i ll give you a generic example that you could use to do what you want.

```
.container_to_slide{
  position:absolute;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
  top:-100%;
}

.container_to_slide.slide_up{
  top:0;
}
```

You can add the class slide_up to your div when you click on 'SIGN_UP' for example and remove the class when you click elsewhere.
(you have to modify top value to make your div hidden when slide_up isn't added and displayed when slide_up is).

You could do something like

```
sign_up.addEventListener('click',function(){
  document.getElementByClassName('.container_to_slide')[0].classList.add('slide_up');
}

document.addEventListener('click',function(){
 if(//code to detect click/touch outside your div//){
   document.getElementByClassName('.container_to_slide')[0].classList.remove('slide_up');
 }
}
```

Comment: Using javascript will cause the elements to function in the same way on other viewports but I would like it to animate in a different way. Such as on desktop on clicking SIGNUP will cause the div to have a modal effect whereas on mobiles the div has to slide up instead of modal effect.

Comment: In that respect I'd advise you lookup media queries and use max-width values to change between the different versions of the same named class. [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com) has a number of articles on how to use them, just do a search on media queries to learn more.

Comment: Btw mediaqueries are accessible from javascript :http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/. You can also detect mobile devices from here so you can adapt your div behaviour depending on your media queries and if you are on a desktop or mobile device.

Comment: Am studying through it. Yet if a fiddle was available it would have been better.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/37h0gbtx/5/ this is an example with media queries and everything :) hope it helps

Comment: its kind of not working. Would you like to check my code? and carry on this conversation in chat? So that after it works out I can give you a upvote.